I'm using clang-format 17.6 and I want to ignore the change in function arguments and parameters if it's on one or more lines
Is there a way to ignorer arguments and parameters of functin if it in one line or multy line.
EX:
uint8_t BufferPutUint8(OUT uint8_t* puBuffOut,
IN uint8_t uVal);
I don't want to change the uint8_t BufferPutUint8() function like this.
uint8_t BufferPutUint8(OUT uint8_t* puBuffOut,IN uint8_t uVal);

and the reverse.
EX:
inline bool BitSetIsSetUInt8(IN uint8_t uBitSet, IN uint8_t uBitMask)
{
   return (uBitSet & uBitMask) == uBitMask;
}


I don't want to change the inline bool BitSetIsSetUInt8() function like this.
inline bool BitSetIsSetUInt8(IN uint8_t uBitSet,
                             IN uint8_t uBitMask)
{
   return (uBitSet & uBitMask) == uBitMask;
}


How are you running clang-format? By default, it doesn't place them on separate lines for me.

I customized the settings in the .clang-format file, and I run clang-format with the --style=file option to read the configuration from the .clang-format file.

What is the .clang-format file? What settings did you customize? Does the behavior remain the same if you use clang-format without that file?

--style=               - Set coding style.  can be:
1. A preset: LLVM, GNU, Google, Chromium, Microsoft,
Mozilla, WebKit.                                                                                     You can find more details in the documentation on the following link
https://releases.llvm.org/17.0.1/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormat.html


The name of the predefined style used as a
fallback in case clang-format is invoked with
-style=file, but can not find the .clang-format
file to use. Defaults to 'LLVM'

